# Fourier Angle Transformation of Picture, C++

Tags: c++, opencv, fft, transformation, vision

I need get angle of object on picture, using Fourier transformation.

I have a picture object, that I rotated. There are no problems with the Fourier realization. It shows me good gradient lines that confirm the correct object angle.

## Q. How do I get angle points from the Fourier gradient, to transform it horizontally?

Answer (score 0):

You don't show us the image or its transform, so I'll assume the gradient lines are indeed clear enough. In that case you'd use the Hough transform. Output is a set of lines, each with an angle.